# Segmentation fault(core dumped) when trying to scanf

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, libc, att

I wrote the code by using Assembly AT&T and it always displays

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

My program should display

> Enter the value for n:

Then it should take the value and then display this value but After taking the value is displays the error I have mentioned above

my code is:

```
    .global _start
  .data

    format: .asciz "Enter the value for n: "
    format1: .asciz "Prime numbers between 1 and %d are: "
    num: .quad 0
    x: .string "%d"
  .text
_start:

  movq $1, %rax
  movq $format, %rdi
  call puts
  movq $0, %rax
  movq $x, %rdi
  xorq $num, %rsi
  call scanf
  movq $60, %rax
  xorq %rdi, %rdi
  syscall
```

what is wrong with it?

Comment: This could be because the stack is misaligned.  Have you tried aligning the stack to 16 bytes before calling functions?

Comment: What is the `xorq %rsi` for? Shouldn't it be `mov $num, %rsi` or `lea num, %rsi`?

Comment: @fuz, assuming that _start is the actual entry point of the executable, and assuming this is Linux, the stack should be aligned.

Comment: It could be because runtime library initialization hasn't been done.

Comment: thanks a lot. it was the issue with xorq. don't know why I put it there

Comment: @prl That, too.  I totally missed this.  OP, you should indeed use the C runtime code to start your program if you intend to use any libc functions.

Comment: @fuz : unless of course he uses a cruntime that doesn't require initialization like `musl`

Comment: @fuz: on Linux, dynamic linking of `libc` lets glibc initialize itself.  You would only have a problem here if you linked with `gcc -static -nostartfiles` instead of just `gcc -nostartfiles`.  But yes, in general write `main` instead of `_start` if you're using libc functions.